# Seg fault when using a variable to offset an array

Tags: c, arrays, char

I am trying to add one character at a time to a char array, called buffer. When I try to add a character to buffer[count], I get a segmentation fault. However if I try to add a character to buffer[0], buffer[1], or any other integer offset it runs fine.  Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    FILE * fp;
    char buffer[100];

    fp = fopen(*(argv+1), "r");

    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("File \"%s\" not found!\n", *(argv+1));
        return 0;
    }

    int curr_char;
    unsigned int count = 0;
    unsigned int min_len;

    while(!feof(fp)){

        curr_char = fgetc(fp);

        if((curr_char >= 32) && (curr_char <= 126)){
            buffer[count] = curr_char;
            printf("%c", curr_char);
            count++;

            if(!((curr_char >= 32) && (curr_char <= 126))){
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Why is buffer[count] not allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access memory only allocated to you when you say `char buffer[100]` it allocates 100 bytes in ram for you. say from the address 1001 to 1100. when you try to say `buffer[453]` it is internally converted to a statement like `*(buffer + 453)`

where buffer base address is 1001. and 453 is added to it then 1454th byte is tried to access which is not allowed as it may lead serious problems like (access data from other process and so on). so kernel halts user execution by sending a signal `SIGSEGV`

EDIT: as it count the file your reading from may have more than 100 bytes. which is again not in range of your process. try increases your buffer size say `char buffer[1024]`

Answer (score 3):

How can you access location 453 like this `buffer[453]` when your buffer is only of size 100? This is UB.

Comment: Ah, sorry I was using that to debug. It should be 'count' instead.

Comment: Are you printing the values of `count` if it exceeds 100 you will get strange results, from weird output to seg faults.

Answer (score 1):

```
char buffer[100];
```

you only can access from `buffer[0]` to `buffer[99]`.
In your code `count` maybe exceed `99`, so there might be a segment fault.

Answer (score 1):

If your input file has more than 100 characters, your `count` will be greater than 100, and you will have a buffer overflow, that is undefined behavior, segmentation fault is one of the common possibilities.

Another common problem in your code is that you use `feof()` incorrectly, see [“while( !feof( file ) )” is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong).